# Debugging a REST Api endpoint with Netbeans, Wordpress & Postman

Tags: netbeans

I am trying to debug a REST Api problem in my WP installation. It crashed and I have to find out why.

My problem is that I can not get Xdebugger to connect to IDE when I access the Api endpoint from postman. I can run just fine from Netbeans standard url when it is started from IDE, but can not get connected to IDE while waiting for connection & triggered from Postman.

I strongly believe that PHP.ini settings are ok. The apache Web server is running on same machine so no path mapping required (not that it should matter).

Machine OS is Windows 10. What I have configured:

1. Configured postman with: POST http://localhost/test/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug&title=Test&status=publish&content=blah
   Authentication = JWT. Set in header.
2. Advanced Web Configuration set to: "proxy='',port: 9000", Debug URL: 'Always ask'

   Start debug -> popup asking for URL: Enter 'http://localhost/test/wp-json/wp/v2/posts' -> IDE waiting for xdebug connect.

   netstat in cmd: netstat -na | find "LISTENING" | find "127"

   Return = Nothing!

Netbeans is not listening! I have checked everything I can think of. Port is definitely set correct in PHP.ini, Tools -> Options->PHP port 9000 matches PHP.ini.

Still I can not get that damned thing to respond. Uuurrgghhhhhh.......frustrating. Can anybody help?

NOTE: The post sent from postman execute just fine with all good status and shows up in WP. Go figure....:-/

```
xdebug.log

[4464] Log opened at 2019-04-24 16:41:09
[4464] I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9000.
[4464] E: Time-out connecting to client (Waited: 200 ms). :-(
[4464] Log closed at 2019-04-24 16:41:09

Xdbug fires but can not find a listner.

PHP.ini

xdebug.idekey = netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/xampp/tmp/xdebug"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_log = "c:/xampp/tmp/xdebug/xdebug_remot.log"
xdebug.show_local_vars = 9
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "c:/xampp/tmp"
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time=36000
```

Answer (score 1):

Yup, resolved this. As usual a good sleep fixed it. My mind is doing housekeeping while I sleep (small house to keep in order :-) and it is solved. The issue was simply to get the IDE to listen for connection requests from Xdebug. So in my project configuration->Run Configuration->Project url: http://localhost/test (whatever your WP project), Index file: index.php. Advanced dialog->Always ask. Save config.

When I start debug;->Url ask popup; http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts is the same as before. Press enter

What happens & what you will see;

1. The Web browser will pop up a window with JSON output from endpoint when you start the debug session from the IDE. Ofcause it does, you just called it from the IDE :-) If you have a breakpoint in index.php it will hit it.
2. What just happened? The IDE sucessfully started an debug session with a receiver. The IDE will now have an open session that will respond on every event that passes through Xdebug with the XDEBUG-SESSION-START=netbeans-xdebug cookie set in the Header/or in URL as a parameter. This ofcause if Netbeans has the same cookie configured in main menu->tools->options->php->debug dialog.

   3. What that does? Yup, every call to any JSON REST Api endpoint is now passing through Xdebug. You can now debug any REST call you need to figure out. Hallelulja - hand in the money :-) Thanks to Derick Rethans the great guy that wrote Xdebug. Super guy :-)

Comment: Well & well again. This was again a case of 'RTFM'. The cause of Api crash was in my code where I did not tell the apply_filter how many parameters to expect. Silly me. This is how it goes when you don't 'RTFM'.

Comment: Found out what caused the crash of Apche server when I started the http://localhost/test URL in a browser window while I had an active debugger session going on the REST Api endpoint. It was ofcause caused by Netbeans project definition where I had the 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' as entry point. If I had opened this URL -> 'http://localhost/test/index.php' the system would run ok. This has been a ride I must say. Learned a lot!

Comment: Please remember that postman will save a cookie which will be sent in http headers even If you delete the Params entry of XDEBUG_.... the cookie will still be sent and everything will work fine until the cookie expire. That can be a challenge to figure out if you come back the next day and nothing work. Easy to fix though. Just add the XDEBUG_SES..... parameter again and you are good.